# Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, spacy

I was trying to upload 'en_core_web_lg' in spacy on google collab.
I executed the following command on the collab cell.

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

[image: I got this message]

Now when I run `nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')`

I get this error message again. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Try `import en_core_web_lg` and then `nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()`

Comment: Did that work?...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nops it did not work...It says,                                                   NameError: name 'en_core_web_lg' is not defined

Comment: Is it Linux or Windows?

Comment: it is Windows 10

Comment: You should uninstall all these modules, and reinstall from a `cmd` launched with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

then:

```
[Ctrl+M] or `Restart runtime` from menu bar
```

works!