# Made an Resume scanning .exe app, taking input from html to Python script and run,but pyinstaller is not able to read my .pdf file showing below error

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spacy

I am using PyInstaller package a python script into an .exe. This script is using spacy to load up the following model: en_core_web_lg. I have already run python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg to download the model locally. The issue is when PyInstaller tries to package up my script it can’t find the model. I get the following error: Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find model 'en\_core\_web\_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733747/cant-find-model-en-core-web-lg-it-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-shortcut-link-a-pyth)

Comment: no, because when i am running locally it is running successfully but after packaging with pyinstaller its not running

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find SpaCy model when packaging with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495437/cant-find-spacy-model-when-packaging-with-pyinstaller)